# CMD script press button

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, vbscript

I'm running this script:

```
@echo off
C:\Users\it.suporte\Desktop\edesta.vbs > siga%computername%.txt
```

but when the vbs file opens generate a pop up window that asks me if I wanna save the information on a .txt file. As you can see I used `> siga%computername%.txt` so it can save the report in a .txt file but since there's a pop up windows it creats a .txt blank.

How can I make it to accept the pop up windows and save it?

my pop up are these lines:

```
If vbYes = MsgBox(ProductData  & vblf & vblf & "Save to a file?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "BackUp Windows Key Information") then
   Save ProductData
End If
```

and I got this function:

```
'Save data to a file
Function Save(Data)
    Dim fso, fName, txt,objshell,UserName
    Set objshell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    'Get current user name
    UserName = objshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserName%")
    'Create a text file on desktop
    fName = "C:\Users\" & UserName & "\Desktop\%computername%.txt"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set txt = fso.CreateTextFile(fName)
    txt.Writeline Data
    txt.Close
End Function
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `If vbYes = MsgBox(ProductData  & vblf & vblf & "Save to a file?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "BackUp Windows Key Information") then`
   `Save ProductData`
`End If`

Comment: I edit the post with the code to get the pop up and the code to save  it.